# Как получить все сборки .NET Framework 4, находящиеся в GAC?

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно получить список сборок в GAC, потому что пишу свою мини-среду, и делаю добавление сборок в проект. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `gacutil [options] [assemblyName | assemblyPath | assemblyListFile]`, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool#examples

Comment: А если VS на ПК не установлена, где скачать gacutil?

Comment: На том пк на котором вы пишете свой код, на том и скачивайте, потом пакуйте в сборку.